# How to validate field inside list before doing a stream()?

Tags: java, java-stream

On the lines where I create the `cardType` and `groupId` variables I get a `"Call Optional#isPresent() before accessing the value"` message from my Sonar. I tried to add `ofNullable().isPresent` to these fields in several ways but none of them made the message go away. Any ideas on how to make this code cleaner?

```
 var customerResponse = customerPromise.get().getContent().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (ofNullable(customerResponse).isPresent()) {

            var cardValuesResponse = customerResponse.getCardValuesResponses();

            if (ofNullable(cardValuesResponse).isPresent()) {

                var cardType = cardValuesResponse.stream().map(CardValuesResponse::getCardType)
                        .findFirst().get();

                var groupId = cardValuesResponse.stream().map(CardValuesResponse::getGroupId)
                        .findFirst().get();

                var discountResponse = discountPromise.get().getContent()
                        .stream().filter(d -> d.getDescription().equals(cardType))
                        .filter(d -> d.getCustomerGroup().equals(groupId))
                        .map(d -> d.getPercent())
                        .findFirst();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where exactly does Sonar report the issue? --- A remark on the code: we can use `Optional.`[`flatMap(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-)`.`[`orElse(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) instead of an `if`-cascade.

Comment: Maybe you're simply trying to get the first element of an empty stream. That's all I can see on first sight

Comment: @Turing85 Sonar report the issue in lines that start with var cardType = ... and var groupId =...

Comment: @Jimmy T. but I don't understand what's happening because before I access the cardType and groupId variables, I already validated if customerResponse isPresent and if cardValuesResponse isPresent. this shouldn't be sufficient?

Comment: What if `cardValuesResponse` is empty?

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks, I will try what you said and will let you know if worked

Comment: @shmosel you're right. I should add a validation when cardValuesResponse appears null

Comment: @NarutoTheKidUzumaki no, it will not work. I operated under a false assumption. Please check [shmosel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123445/how-to-validate-field-inside-list-before-doing-a-stream#comment120403453_68123445).

Comment: `ofNullable(cardValuesResponse).isPresent()` is completely pointless btw. Just check `cardValuesResponse != null`.

Comment: In the first line, 
`var customerResponse = customerPromise.get()`

Is "customerPromise" an Optional, or something else?
If it's an Optional, you'll want to check if that is present, or map over it, or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified a lot by using .ifPresent instead of .isPresent and .get, and you get the interim null checks for free through the .map steps. Start with this:

```
customerPromise.get()
               .getContent()
               .stream()
               .findFirst()
               .map(CustomerResponse::getCardValuesResponse)
               .ifPresent(
                 cardValuesResponse -> {
                    // handle card data here
                 }
               );
```